# MySQL how to display average of column and table

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get output like:

```
Average score
10
col1   col2  score
...
```

Using

```
SELECT AVG(Score), *
FROM (
SUM(...) AS col1
SUM(...) AS col2
SUM(...) AS Score
) AS T1
```

This is working when I select only AVG(Score) or * but not both. Is there any way I can do this without duplicating the code?

Here's the error I get when I try:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 27: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check 
the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right 
syntax to use near '*
FROM (
SELECT
    testresults.hostname AS Hostname,
    hostinfo.env A' at line 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `*` with other columns. You can either do:

```
 SELECT * FROM...
```

or

```
 SELECT col1, col2, col3... FROM...
```

but not

```
 SELECT col1, col2, col3, * FROM...
```

example:

```
mysql> SELECT id FROM users LIMIT 5;
+----+
| id |
+----+
| 18 |
| 22 |
| 23 |
| 26 |
| 27 |
+----+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT id, * FROM users LIMIT 5;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* FROM users LIMIT 5' at line 1
```

Comment: Thanks! But can I reference the derived table multiple times? I don't want to keep recalculating everything.

Comment: Sure. With the full query and a data sample I could help you further. You won't be able to fetch the AVG after doing a SUM, but you can get a SUM and a COUNT(*) and you will have AVG = SUM(col) / COUNT(*)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  
test t,
(SELECT AVG(score) AS average_score
 FROM test) a;
```

Here's the **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d8169e/3/0)**.